# How to handle multiple Volley-Responses in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have a VolleyHandler class with two methods. One method fetches the id of an user and the other fetches a json array with some transaction data. There is also a callback interface "VolleyListener" with a "showResult" method in the same class. This method gets called in the onResponse (volleyListener.showResult(response);)
My main activity implements the interface.
Now I want to get the user id and based on this id I want to fetch the transaction data. - How should I differentiate between the two responses in the showResult method? Should I use two seperate showResult methods?

Comment: The best way would be to use 2 different methods. You can create two methods inside your interface: `showUserResults` and `showTransactionResults` and use them

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have implemented these two methods, but now I have another question. I am trying to fetch the id in my onCreateView and based on this id I want to fetch some transaction data. (volleyHandler.getID(username); volleyHandler.getTotalSum(id);). How is it possilbe to use the id I get as JSONresponse? I think I can't change a class variable in the showUserResults method but I need the id for the transaction data...

Comment: You can change the class variable inside the method if it has global scope. You should declare `id` as a global and initialize it to an invalid value and then  use it inside the 2nd method. Let me know if you need an example